# Erro com HtmlUnit / WebClient / WildFly10

Tags: java, html, wildfly

Estou tentando utilizar o `htmlunit` mas está acontecendo:

*** Ambiente/Servidor: `WildFly10`

Ao executar o seguinte comando:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_45);
```

Acontece o erro:

> ```
> 17:34:19,139 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-4) Failed to define class com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement in Module "deployment.teste.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomElement (Module "deployment.teste.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
> at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:358)
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
>    .
>    .
>    .
> Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/BaseFrameElement (Module "deployment.teste.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement (Module "deployment..war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomElement (Module "deployment.sigeap.war:main" from Service Module Loader): org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
> at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
> at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
> ... 50 more  
>    .
>    .
>    .
> 17:34:19,168 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /teste/pages/teste/teste.jsf: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/BaseFrameElement (Module "deployment.teste.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link
> ```

Maven:

```
<dependency>     
     <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>     
     <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>            
     <version>2.23</version> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Eu não consegui ler tudo, mas o erro parece ser no uso do `javax.faces`

Comment: Resolvi retirando do `Maven` e adicionando o `.jar` diretamente no projeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estava com o mesmo problema, mas resolvi colocando uma versão compatível com meu projeto. Descobri que algumas bibliotecas de meu projeto estavam chocando com o HtmlUnit. Quando eu modifiquei a versão do HtmlUnit que continha as mesmas dependências de meu projeto tudo funcionou corretamente.

Httpclient-4.2.1 (usado em meu projeto) estava em conflito com o HtmlUnit-2.21 (que usa httpclient-4.5.2.jar). Então eu mudei para a versão HtmlUnit 2.10 (que usa Httpclient-4.2.1) e tudo funcionou corretamente.